# issue with serial port + C# data receiving

Tags: c#, serial-port, arduino

I want to transfer data that appears in Arduino to my C# application and do not know what's wrong in my code.
Here comes Arduino code:

```
int switchPin = 7;
int ledPin = 13;
boolean lastButton = LOW;
boolean currentButton = LOW;
boolean flashLight = LOW;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(switchPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

boolean debounce(boolean last)
{
  boolean current = digitalRead(switchPin);
  if (last != current)
  {
    delay(5);
    current = digitalRead(switchPin);
  }
  return current;
}

void loop()
{
  currentButton = debounce(lastButton);
  if (lastButton == LOW && currentButton == HIGH)
  {
    Serial.print("UP");

    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  }
  if (lastButton == HIGH && currentButton == LOW)
  {
    Serial.print("DOWN");

    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }

  lastButton = currentButton;
}
```

As you can see, this simple sketch sends message to port while the button is pressed.
I have created a console C# app to receive data:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace ArduinoTestApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600);
            port.Open();
            string lane;
            while (true)
            {
                lane = port.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine(lane);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

But when I push the button console is still empty.
Tell me what's wrong, please!

Comment: with port.ReadLine() I think you'll need to send a CR or LF or maybe both??

Comment: @kenny: what do you mean about "CR or LF" ? can you write some further information? :)

Comment: Are you missing port.Close() ? It looks like your code is not releasing resources of potential un-managed code.

Comment: @ElYusubov: should i put it after my cycle or where?
btw does it matter if i close the port?

Comment: Probably, it needs to be closed before Main method is finished. Let me know the result please.

Comment: @ElYusubov: it is unreacheble code by the way. Because the cycle is while(true), so it won't help. Didn't help :( Even if I close port in the cycle.

Comment: ReadLine - reads up to NewLine value in the input buffer.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readline.aspx  NewLine - A value that represents the end of a line. The default is a line feed,

Comment: @kenny: so how to read "UP" or "DOWN" than? if ReadLine can't do it.
btw i've changed "Serial.print("UP");" to "Serial.println("UP");" but nothing has changed.

Comment: @arcadia I don't know what Serial.println() does, but it sounds like the right thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all simple. I forget to write

> Serial.begin()

:D That's all. Now it works.